# Input Date value Property django

Tags: html, django, date

I'm trying to display the value of a date field from the database in my HTML but the field still shows blank text

I've tried using the Django pipe when setting the value of the date. When I even use the same exact code in the label it works well but doesn't just work in the date field

This is my views.py file

```
def all(request):
    employees = Employee.objects.all().order_by('last_name')
    departments = Department.objects.all()
    table = EmployeeTable(employees)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    context =  {
        'table':table,
        'employees':employees,
        'departments':departments
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        name = last_name +' '+first_name
        employee_id = request.POST['employee_id']
        email = request.POST['email']
        department = Department.objects.get(dept_name = request.POST['department'])
        address = request.POST['address']
        employment_type = request.POST['employment_type']
        employment_status = request.POST['employment_status']
        role = request.POST['role']
        marital_status = request.POST['marital_status']
        gender = request.POST['gender']
        join_date = request.POST['join_date']
        end_date = None if len(request.POST['end_date']) ==0 else request.POST['end_date']
        location = request.POST['location']
        credentials = request.POST['credentials']
        passport = request.POST['passport']
        hod = request.POST['hod']
        phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']
        date_of_birth = request.POST['date_of_birth']
        date_added = datetime.now()
```

This my HTML code

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for='date_of_birth' class="control-label">Date of Birth
       {{employee.date_of_birth|date:'Y/m/d'}}  
       {{employee.date_of_birth|date:'m-d-Y'}}  
       {{employee.date_of_birth|date:'SHORT_DATE_FORMAT'}} <span class="text- 
       danger">*</span>
     </label>
     <input name='date_of_birth' type="date"  class="form-control" value = " 
     {{employee.date_of_birth|date:'m/d/Y'}} " >
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: It looks like the spacing is off, probably you should use `value="{{employee.date_of_birth|date:'m/d/Y'}}">`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the `value=...` attribute for an [**`<input type="date">`** [mozilla-doc]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) is:

> A `DOMString` representing a date in **`YYYY-MM-DD` format**, or empty.

So your `<input>` element should be:

```
<input type="date" value="{{employee.date_of_birth|date:'Y-m-d'}}" name="date_of_birth" class="form-control">
```